# Fastest rendering fonts in gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, fonts, gnome-terminal

So I was reading an article on usesthis.com and he states "...I use the Terminus font because it is a bitmap font that renders fast and cleanly."

Is this true? Which font renders the fastest in gnome-terminal? Are bitmap fonts often faster? Is it really a noticeable difference from any other font, especially in a terminal? How does one go about testing the render speed of a font?

*I did try opening gnome-terminal with my previous font (Dejavu Sans Mono) and Terminus and with DVSM, it takes a moment for text to appear but with Terminus it is instant.*

Answer (score 1):

I really don't perceive any change in rendering speed on my terminal with different kinds of fonts (my notebook has an Intel Celeron at 2 GHz, so I should notice a change if there were any). I've even tried with `sans` and `serif` fonts (non-monospace) and using `hinting` but I don't notice any increase or decrease on performance of regular, non-intensive use at all. Maybe it has something to do with the x drivers of your machine. By the way I'm on Fedora 20, 64 bits.

However, I conducted a little experiment with some different fonts: `terminus`, `dejavu mono` (which is the same as `monospace`), `liberation mono` and `open sans`. On two different terminal emulators and with different hinting configurations:

1. Gnome Terminal, 1 million lines, 8192 lines buffer:

   - Full font hinting:

     - terminus 9

       - Startup time: `0.348`
       - Execution time: `16.137`
     - monospace 9

       - Startup time: `0.344`
       - Execution time: `16.199`
     - liberation mono 9

       - Startup time: `0.357`
       - Execution time: `16.120`
     - open sans 9

       - Startup time: `0.342`
       - Execution time: `16.261`
   - Font hinting disabled:

     - terminus 9

       - Startup time: `0.351`
       - Execution time: `16.134`
     - monospace 9

       - Startup time: `0.336`
       - Execution time: `16.095`
     - liberation mono 9

       - Startup time: `0.349`
       - Execution time: `16.391`
     - open sans 9

       - Startup time: `0.352`
       - Execution time: `16.157`
2. XFCE4 Terminal, 1 million lines, 8192 lines buffer:

   - Full font hinting:

     - terminus 9

       - Startup time: `0.064`
       - Execution time: `16.127`
     - monospace 9

       - Startup time: `0.062`
       - Execution time: `16.104`

All the times were measured using the `time` command and taken only the `real` value, the command was run 10 times for each different font configuration and the value displayed here is the mean of each batch of measures, a new terminal was used for every execution.

As you can see **there's not** any noticeable difference between the different fonts and even with or without hinting, however, the only thing that jumps into sight is the difference of the startup times between the `gnome-terminal` and the `xfce4-terminal`, where gnome is *~554% slower* than xfce, but in normal circumstances this is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really matters. If you do a stress-test, you'll find gnome-terminal spending most of its time handling the input; updating the display is relatively cheap compared to this.

Note that for many years there was a stupid bug which made gnome-terminal (and all vte-based emulators) very slow. It was fixed in vte-0.36, bringing a ~10x improvement.